# Why should I should url routes to the user in a single page application?

Tags: web-applications, ajax, routing

Why a single page application is a desktop client replacement why should I show certain url`s in the url bar of the browser.

Why is mysite.com not enough.

My question to you guys is now:

What are the reasons and advantages for the user to show such an url like mysite.com/customers/3

Are there any reasons like the user wants to be able and bookmark a site and this would need an URI ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bookmarks are one reason; another reason is that you want to keep the back/forward buttons functioning according to the user's expectation. Users don't care whether it's a single-page application or not; they hit "back" and expect to go back one conceptual step. Without special precautions, the "back" button will take them *away* from your single page, which is invariably not what they expect, and it can be seriously annoying.

Comment: so should I create urls for every page also when I do a HttpDelete? For what actions would an url make sense? Does a user want to bookmark an edit formular? I can not think of that... what do you think?

Comment: I think you should give visible URLs to everything where a bookmark could work. Deleting an item will probably not send users to a new page specific to that action, so that's a case where you cannot really. For editing, it is possible, so I think you should. Let users figure out for themselves if it is useful in any way. What do you lose by giving the option to bookmark?

Answer (score 3):

It also means if their connection drops out they can refresh the current page easily.